# Intellij project hosted on GitHub showing up as a subversion project?

Tags: git, svn, github, intellij-idea

I have a project that I pushed to github in intellij via the "share code" option.  I reopened the project today only to find that my git-specific options have been replaced by those for subversion.  I tried cloning a version of my code into a new project, thinking certianly intellij could figure out where it came from that way, but to no avail.  I still don't have the ability to push/pull/view history via intellij (though I still can via the command line in the project directory).

Is there a way to correct this?  This is the current content of the vcs.xml file in the idea directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="" vcs="svn" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Thanks, as always (I loooove this forum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change **Subversion** to **Git** in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Version Control`.

Comment: That was it thanks.  Note for others who find this question: Adding Git was actually not enough.  I also had to remove subversion from the list.